# How does groovy distinguish division from strings?

Tags: parsing, groovy, groovyshell

Groovy supports `/` as a division operator:

```
groovy> 1 / 2
===> 0.5
```

It supports `/` as a string delimiter, which can even be multiline:

```
groovy> x = /foo/
===> foo
groovy:000> x = /foo
groovy:001> bar/
===> foo
bar
```

Given this, why can't I evaluate a slashy-string literal in groovysh?

```
groovy:000> /foo/
groovy:001>
```

clearly groovysh thinks this is unterminated for some reason.

How does groovy avoid getting confused between division and strings? What does this code mean:

```
groovy> f / 2
```

Is this a function call `f(/2 .../)` where `/` is beginning a multiline slashy-string, or `f` divided by 2?

Comment: That means `f` divided by 2.  There's no closing `/` and groovy won't let you use that form even if there were `f / 2 /` as it's ambiguous.  Not sure why `/foo/` doesn't work in the groovy shell...it works in the Groovy Console

Answer (score 2):

### How does Groovy distinguish division from strings?

I'm not entirely sure how Groovy does it, but I'll describe how I'd do it, and I'd be very surprised if Groovy didn't work in a similar way.

Most parsing algorithms I've heard of ([Shunting-yard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), [Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_parser), etc) recognize two distinct kinds of tokens:

- Those that expect to be preceded by an expression (infix operators, postfix operators, closing parentheses, etc). If one of these is not preceded by an expression, it's a syntax error.
- Those that do not expect to be preceded by an expression (prefix operators, opening parentheses, identifiers, literals, etc). If one of these is preceded by an expression, it's a syntax error.

To make things easier, from this point onward I'm going to refer to the former kind of token as an **operator** and the latter as a **non-operator**.

Now, the interesting thing about this distinction is that it's made not based on what the token actually is, but rather on the immediate context, particularly the preceding tokens. Because of this, the same token can be interpreted very differently depending on its position in the code, and whether the parser classifies it as an operator or a non-operator. For example, the '`-`' token, if in an operator position, denotes a subtraction, but the same token in a non-operator position is a negation. There is no issue deciding whether a '`-`' is a subtraction operator or not, because you can tell based on its context.

The same is, in general, true for the '`/`' character in Groovy. If preceded by an expression, it's interpreted as an operator, which means it's a division. Otherwise, it's a non-operator, which makes it a string literal. So, you can generally tell if a '`/`' is a division or not, by looking at the token that immediately precedes it:

- The '`/`' is a **division** if it follows an identifier, literal, postfix operator, closing parenthesis, or other token that denotes the end of an expression.
- The '`/`' begins a **string** if it follows a prefix operator, infix operator, opening parenthesis, or other such token, or if it begins a line.

Of course, it isn't quite so simple in practice. Groovy is designed to be flexible in the face of various styles and uses, and therefore things like semicolons or parentheses are often optional. This can make parsing somewhat ambiguous at times. For example, say our parser comes across the following line:

```
println / foo
```

This is most likely an attempt to print a multiline string: `foo` is the beginning of a string being passed to `println` as an argument, and the optional parentheses around the argument list are left out. Of course, to a simple parser it looks like a division. I expect the Groovy parser can tell the difference by reading ahead to the following lines to see which interpretation does not give an error, but for something like `groovysh` that is literally impossible (since, as a repl, it doesn't yet have access to more lines), so it's forced to just guess.

### Why can't I evaluate a slashy-string literal in groovysh?

As before, I don't know the exact reason, but I do know that because `groovysh` is a repl, it's bound to have more trouble with the more ambiguous rules. Even so, a simple single-line slashy-string is pretty unambiguous, so I believe something else may be going on here. Here is the result of me playing with various forms in `groovysh`:

```
> /foo             - unexpected char: '/' @ line 2, column 1.
> /foo/            - awaits further input
> /foo/bar         - unexpected char: '/' @ line 2, column 1.
> /foo/bar/        - awaits further input
> /foo/ + 'bar'    - unexpected char: '/' @ line 2, column 1.
> 'foo' + /bar/    - evaluates to 'foobar'
>  /foo/           - evaluates to 'foo'
>  /foo            - awaits further input
>  /foo/bar        - Unknown property: bar
```

It appears that something strange happens when a '`/`' character is the first character in a line. The pattern it appears to follow (as far as I can tell) is this:

- A slash as the first character of a line begins a strange parsing mode.
- In this mode, every line that ends with a slash followed by nothing but whitespace causes the repl to await further lines.
- On the first line that ends with something other than a slash (or whitespace following a slash), the error `unexpected char: '/' @ line 2, column 1.` is printed.

I've also noticed a couple of interesting points regarding this:

- Both forward slashes (`/`) and backslashes (`\`) appear to count, and seem to be completely interchangeable, in this special mode.
- This does not appear to happen at all in `groovyConsole` or in actual Groovy files.
- Putting any whitespace before the opening slash character causes `groovysh` to interpret it correctly, but only if the opening slash is a forward slash, not a backslash.

So, I personally expect that this is just a quirk of `groovysh`, either a bug or some under-documented feature I haven't heard about.